# Python logging is outputting with the time 4 hours ahead of system

Tags: python

My system is set to EDT in Linux, and I can confirm this in Python with datetime.now(). However the logger is outputting 4 hours ahead. What could be the cause of this?

EDIT: Logging config looks like this:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
lf = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")

mylogger = logging.getLogger('mylogger')
mylogger .setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

lsh = logging.StreamHandler()
lsh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
lsh.setFormatter(lf)
mylogger.addHandler(lsh)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logger is using UTC time. If you show us your code it would be possible to say exactly why.

Comment: Edited with more details of the logging config.

Comment: Do you need more code than what I've showed? That is about all there is with relation to the logger.

Comment: @rhubarb: what version of Python are you using?

Comment: @rhubarb: by default logging uses `time.localtime` to produce time stamp. You could inspect `logging` module yourself to make sure that nothing is changed there, it's usually located at `/usr/lib/python2.6/logging.py/__init__.py`

Answer (score 1):

I think it is significant that 4 hours ahead is GMT for you. Poking around logging's code - it seems that it uses `time` rather than `datetime`. Apparently they work differently in figuring out the localtime.

What does the following output?:

```
import time
print time.tzname
```

AFAIK, that controls the offset used by logging. According to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.tzset), you want to tweak your "system's zoneinfo database to specify the timezone rules" (`man tzfile`).

Comment: It says EDT, EST. So that doesn't seem to be the problem.